# Gleaning data from tab-delimited txt file with missing values

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, nosql

I need to get make a json file from a whitespace-delineated txt file.

**However**:
1. the whitespaces are inconsistent in length and 
2. some of the data of each "column" is missing.

A single row looks like this in the txt file:

```
 5653   Phrakhtaes  Phrakhtaes      34.56717    33.02724    L   LCTY    GB      05              0       32  Asia/Nicosia    2014-09
```

Ultimately, this data will go onto Redis.  But without some means of creating keys for each "column", I don't see how I can work with this data.

Please, I could really use the help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Simply just split where there are 2 or more spaces in between your data:

```js
var line = "5653   Phrakhtaes  Phrakhtaes      34.56717    33.02724    L   LCTY    GB      05              0       32  Asia/Nicosia    2014-09";

console.log(line.split(/  +/));
```

As far as data missing, I'd recommend you just check the length of the array, and `<` the number of expected results, you simply discard. The only other option is to loop through, and judge which one may be missing (Based on string type, if it's in integer, uppercase, etc...) if there are a variable number of spaces in between data points.

Comment: Right.  But, how can I assign a key to each "column"/value if each "row"/line of the txt is inconsistent from the next "row"/line?

Comment: I recommend editing your post, including a minimal example where we can see these inconsistencies, and then give us your expected result. See creating a [mcve].